# How to use a semicolon as a list separator for email addresses

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have an Access form with several comboboxes which contain stakeholder information, including email addresses. Not all comboboxes are filled for each record.

I have a button on the form that will `SendObject` on click. I want that button to send an email to all stakeholders in a given record. I want to separate the inputs in the "To" section of the `SendObject` command.

The VBA does not recognize the semicolon as a list separator when listing the comboboxes I want included in the "To" portion of SendObject.
It gives me a compile error message.

> "Expected: End of Statement"

I changed the list separator in the Control Panel from comma to semicolon, but this hasn't solved the issue.

Example of the code:

```vb
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , Me.cmb_UnitPOC_ST.Column(1);& Me.cmb_LeadUnitST2.Column(1);Me.cmb_LeadUnitST3.Column(1);Me.cmb_LeadUnitST4.Column(1);Me.cmb_LeadUnitST5.Column(1), , , _
  Me.txb_ProjectName & " (" & Me.txb_ID & "): " & Me.[Lead], , True`
```

My workaround was to separate the comboboxes with & ";" &. This got rid of the "Expected: End of Statement" compile error message. However, if there are more than two consecutive empty combo boxes, I get an error message when I click the button and try to execute the `SendObject` command. The error message states "Unknown message recipients." I found the issue is the consecutive semicolons that come from having multiple empty fields.

Example of the code:

```vb
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , Me.cmb_UnitPOC_ST.Column(1) & ";" & _
  Me.cmb_LeadUnitST2.Column(1) & ";" & Me.cmb_LeadUnitST3.Column(1) & ";" & _
  Me.cmb_LeadUnitST4.Column(1) & ";" & Me.cmb_LeadUnitST5.Column(1), , , _
  Me.txb_ProjectName & " (" & Me.txb_ID & "): " & Me.[Lead], , True
```

I tried several different symbols in the `&" "&`, but Outlook requires a semicolon to separate email addresses and will not recognize commas, other symbols, spaces, or tabs to separate email addresses (this will be used by many people so I can't change a setting on my Outlook to solve this problem).
I tried adding a step by compiling the emails in a separate text box and using that text box as the "To" input but ran into similar issues.
I tried using comma as a list separator but that creates the same compile error message as the semicolon.
I tried changing the list separator in the Control Panel to "/" and to "|" but VBA does not recognize either as a list separator.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would put the "To" list together as a separate string variable. You'll have to test each combo with an IsNull() before you append it to your list string.
something like:
`If not isNull(cboOne) then
    strTo = cboOne
end if
If not isNull(cboTwo) then
    strTo = strTo & ";" & cboTwo
end if`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put code in code boxes (and not in normal text) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `To` part takes a string. If you have more than one email address, you must join them together and outlook expects `;` as delimiter.

Make a helper function that can generate your `To` address list.
something like this:

```
Public Function AddMailAddress(address As String, newaddress As String)

    If (address = "") And (newaddress = "") Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If address = "" Then
        address = newaddress
    Else

        If Not newaddress = "" Then
            If VBA.Right(address, 1) = ";" Then
                address = address & newaddress
            Else
                address = address & ";" & newaddress
            End If
        End If
    End If


    AddMailAddress = address

End Function
```

and then add your mail addresses one by one :

```
Dim toAddress as string
Dim subject   as string

toAddress = AddMailAddress(toAddress, nz(Me.cmb_UnitPOC_ST.Column(1),""))
toAddress = AddMailAddress(toAddress, nz(Me.cmb_LeadUnitST2.Column(1),""))
toAddress = AddMailAddress(toAddress, nz(Me.cmb_LeadUnitST3.Column(1),""))
toAddress = AddMailAddress(toAddress, nz(Me.cmb_LeadUnitST4.Column(1),""))
toAddress = AddMailAddress(toAddress, nz(Me.cmb_LeadUnitST5.Column(1),""))
subject = Me.txb_ProjectName & " (" & Me.txb_ID & "): " & Me.[Lead]
```

And then use it like

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, To:= toAddress, Subject:= subject, EditMessage:= True
```

PS: the helper function is just a concept, you must adapt it according to your needs

Comment: This worked when there are values in all of the combo boxes, but if I had values in fewer than all 5 combo boxes I got a "Run-time Error '94': Invalid Use of Null"  error message, highlighting the first "to address = AddMailAddress..." line with an empty combo box.

Below is how it looks in my window (btw I'm new at this and can't figure out how to put code in the code box)

Comment: It looks like the full code is too long to add in the reply, but basically the layout looks like this:
Your Helper Function
Private Sub cmd_EmailAF_Click()
Your code that lists all the toAddress=
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , toAddress, , , subject, , True
End Sub

Sorry again for not putting the code in a code box, I couldn't figure that out for the replies.

Comment: You can change the helper to accept nulls by setting new `newaddress as variant`, or you can pre check null values using `nz()` function. See edited answer

Comment: Adding the nz() as shown in your edited answer got the trick done. Thanks very much. How do you give props on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Region issues? What is your Windows list separator: ";" or ","? If it is "," you must use it in place of ";".

To check that open Control Panel, Region, click "Additional Settings..." then check what is in "List Separator" field. What you see there, that is what Office is using for a list separator.

Comment: My computer's default list separator is ",", but "," separates the different parts of the command for SendObject. I.e., if I put a "," after any item it jumps to the next part of the command, like going from "To" to "CC". I changed the list separator from "," to ";" in the Control Panel but that did not fix the issue - it may be because I have very limited Admin permissions on this computer. Either way, the answer krish KM gave me worked.

Comment: Well, I did not mean that this will change: DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , - here is always comma! What I meant is a character for list separator (which depends on Region Settings).